# Issues Installing pdftotext on MacOS using Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pdftotext

I am newer to programming and am having trouble installing pdftotext in Anaconda, using Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6 and Python 3.6.7. I have installed all the dependencies recommended (https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext) but have not been able to successfully install pdftotext.

Errors include:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/3_/T/pip-install-ak3q4wz7/pdftotext/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/3_/T/pip-install-ak3q4wz7/pdftotext/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/3_/T/pip-install-ak3q4wz7/pdftotext/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /private/var/folders/3_//T/pip-install-ak3q4wz7/pdftotext/
Complete output (3 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using pdftotext from poppler instead of the package listed above. This required the installation of poppler using conda-forge in Anaconda.

For Mac:

```
conda create -n envname python=3.7
conda activate envname
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install poppler
```

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

This suggests that you want to install at least [one more dependency](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/setuptools):

```
$ conda install setuptools
```

Or `pip install`, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks J_H. I tried your recommendation and successfully installed setuptools, but still get the same error.